# Two arguments expected instead of three error

Tags: python, dictionary

The following code is giving me an error when I am trying to add three items to my dictionary:

```
from collections import deque

#setting up a dictionary so that only the recent most recent values are stored
player_stats = {}
with open("players.dat") as f:
    for line in f:
        classcode, name, score = line.split()
        player_stats.setdefault(classcode, name, deque(maxlen=3))  
        player_stats[name].append(int(score))       

print(player_stats)
```

My data is:

**1 Rooney 56**   and so on for other players. I cant see what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments it is clear that names are unique *per class*, that is to say that a name and class code together are unique identifiers for a player. Someone with the same name in a different class is not the same person.

As such, you just track the `(classcode, name)` tuples as the keys for your `player_stats` dictionary:

```
from collections import deque

#setting up a dictionary so that only the recent most recent values are stored
player_stats = {}
with open("players.dat") as f:
    for line in f:
        classcode, name, score = line.split()
        key, score = (classcode, name), int(score)
        player_stats.setdefault(key, deque(maxlen=3)).append(score)

print(player_stats)
```

This tracks the last three score for each `classcode` + `name` combination.

Comment: Yes that works thanks and I have tested average and total and max on it and that works too. Thanks we got there in the end. I initially tried to get the last three values to go in to a class rather than a dictionary but had no luck. Is there a way of doing this but with a class?

Comment: A class doesn't buy you anything here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that dicts take key/value pairs so you need to group the extra information. The following example will keep the last 3 `classcode, score` pairs for each player. I am using `defaultdict` instead of `getdefault` because `getdefault` will create (and usually immediately discard) a deque for every get.

```
from collections import deque, defaultdict

#setting up a dictionary so that only the recent most recent values are stored
player_stats = defaultdict(lambda:deque(maxlen=3))
with open("players.dat") as f:
    for line in f:
        classcode, name, score = line.split()
        player_stats[name].append((classcode, int(score)))      

print(player_stats)
```

If you'd rather track the last 3 scores for each class code, you could

```
from collections import deque, defaultdict

#setting up a dictionary so that only the recent most recent values are stored
player_stats = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: deque(maxlen=3)))
with open("players.dat") as f:
    for line in f:
        classcode, name, score = line.split()
        player_stats[name][classcode].append(int(score))

print(player_stats)
```

Comment: your first option give me all the scores for all of the players. I only need the most recent three scores for each player. Your second option throws back error:adding values to dictionary test.py", line 13, in <module>
    player_stats = defaultdict(defaultdict(lambda: deque))
TypeError: first argument must be callable

Comment: my appologies, I pasted old examples before I put lambdas in the right place.